Python connection to Elasticsearch encountered an error
https  or  http
es_host = 'https://ip:port'
#es_host = 'http://ip:port'
es_username = 'root'
es_password = 'password'
 
# 创建Elasticsearch客户端
es = Elasticsearch(hosts=es_host,http_auth=(es_username, es_password),verify_certs=False)

When I connect through host ('https://ip:port) ,Error reporting（SSLError:

ConnectionError([SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number
(_ssl.c:1129)) caused by: SSLError([SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong
version number (_ssl.c:1129))）

When I connect through host ('http://ip:port) ,Error reporting（ConnectionError:

ConnectionError(('Connection aborted.',
BadStatusLine('J\x00\x00\x00\n'))) caused by:
ProtocolError(('Connection aborted.',
BadStatusLine('J\x00\x00\x00\n')))） your text

iReduced elasticsearch version to 7.15.0,From TSLerror to SSllerror
I also tried   verify_certs=False, It doesn't work
i hope print(es.ping()) is True

maybe it needs to update library OpenSSL - it is not part of Python so it may need to download and install it manually.

I have found a solution，use http  donot use https  it's work
